# error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to double[]

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code which receives three different combinations of mass and volume and then stores each value into two different arrays: mass and volume.
It is also required that I create a method in order to calculate the density.
However, when I try to call the method in order to calculate with the inputted masses and volumes, I receive an error.

This is the error:

> Density.java:19: error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted
>   to double[]
>   System.out.printf("%.2f",calculateDensity(mass[0],volume[0]));

Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with `-Xdiags:verbose` to get full output
1 error
Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Density {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        double [] mass = new double[3];
        double [] volume = new double[3];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the mass and volume for your three compounds.");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3;i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter mass in grams:  ");
            mass[i] = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter volume in millimeters:  ");
            volume[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        }

        System.out.print("The density for mass = ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", mass[0]);
        System.out.print("g and volume = ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", volume[0]);
        System.out.print("ml is: ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f",calculateDensity(mass[0],volume[0]));
    }

    public static void calculateDensity (double[] mass, double[] volume) {
        double [] density = new double [3];
        density[0] = mass[0] / volume[0];
    }
}
```

I would love some help trying to figure out what is wrong. I am not entirely sure how to define methods with arrays or call methods using arrays.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: calculateDensity expects an **array of doubles** (`double[]`). But you're passing `mass[0]`which a double, not an array.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error message already says exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

calculateDensity needs double as parameters not double[].
 You also need to return a double from density otherwise you can't print something out.

```
public static double calculateDensity (double mass, double volume){
//your code
return density;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

calculateDensity parameters are arrays (double[]) but you pass (mass[0],volume[0]), which is primitive type double.

Change your method paameters to:

```
public static void calculateDensity (double mass, double volume)
```

Comment: Thanks it works great now! I did have to make it a public static double rather than void and now I just have it return density.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Density {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        double [] mass = new double[3];
        double [] volume = new double[3];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the mass and volume for your three compounds.");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3;i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter mass in grams:  ");
            mass[i] = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter volume in millimeters:  ");
            volume[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        }

        System.out.print("The density for mass = ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", mass[0]);
        System.out.print("g and volume = ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", volume[0]);
        System.out.print("ml is: ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f",calculateDensity(mass[0],volume[0]));
    }

    public static double calculateDensity (double mass, double volume) {
        return  mass / volume;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the requirement to print all three outputs and not just the first one and you need to have the method exactly as `public static void calculateDensity (double[] mass, double[] volume)`
Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double [] mass = new double [3];
    double [] volume = new double [3];
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the mass and volume for your 3 compounds.\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter mass in grams: ");
        mass [i] = s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("Enter volume in milliliters: ");
        volume [i] = s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();
    }
    s.close();
    calculateDensity(mass, volume);
}
public static void calculateDensity(double[] mass, double[] volume) {

    System.out.printf("The density for mass = %.2f g and volume = %.2f ml is: %.2f g/ml\n\n", mass[0], volume[0], (mass[0] / volume[0]));
    System.out.printf("The density for mass = %.2f g and volume = %.2f ml is: %.2f g/ml\n\n", mass[1], volume[1], (mass[1] / volume[1]));
    System.out.printf("The density for mass = %.2f g and volume = %.2f ml is: %.2f g/ml\n\n", mass[2], volume[2], (mass[2] / volume[2]));   
}
```

This may not be the best, but it works as prescribed.